# What is the difference between a Dictionary and a ExpandoObject casted as a Dictionary that prevents Scriban Template Render from working?

Tags: c#, scriban

Ir am trying to render content that is loaded from a CSV with Scriban. Unfortunately, its not rendering correctly unless I explicitly call ToDictionary to create another dictionary and I would like to understand why, and proper ways to fix it.

```cs
var reader = new StreamReader(csvFile.ToString());
var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
    
var templateStr = "|{{ReportID}}|";

foreach(ExpandoObject record in records){
    var template = Template.Parse(templateStr);
    var row = (IDictionary<string,object>)record;

    var reportID = row["ReportID"]; // Works as dictionary

    var expando = template.Render(record);
    var expandoCast = template.Render(row);
    var expandoToDictionary = template.Render(record.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value));

    Console.WriteLine($"{reportID} expando: {expando} expandoCast:{expandoCast} expandoToDictionary:{expandoToDictionary}");  
}
```

Prints

> 3940268 expando: || expandoCast:|| expandoToDictionary:|3940268|

Why does the template not render the keys? Is there a better way to solve this without creating a new dictionary?

Comment: What happens if you cast to Dictionary<string, object> instead of IDictionary?

Comment: I get this error: `error CS0039: Cannot convert type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion`

Comment: And if you try passing your expandoobject to the dictionary constructor like this?
var row = new Dictionary<string, object>(record);

Comment: This seems to work. Will this connect the row to the original object or make a copy?